# route53 healthcheck always healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to use Route53 for automatic failover. The problem I am having is that even though the CloudWatch alarm I am using in the health check is in an Alarm state, the health check is still reporting as healthy, and the DNS is still resolving to the faulty host (I'm simulating this by stopping the instance - I've set CloudWatch to treat missing metrics as an alarm).  See screenshots for the configuration of my alarm.

[Health check configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VBkP.png)

As you can see, this health check is reporting as healthy:

[Health check status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXshg.png)

Comment: It's interesting that the status message says the health checker "didn't have enough data."  Does it say that same thing when the alarm status is OK as well?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have since taken a different approach and used an aws load balancer.  However I have just tried, creating a new alarm and health check and this is the status message: `Success: 3 datapoints were not greater than or equal to the threshold (85.0)` So I guess it was not behaving as I expected, although not incorrectly.